# Generate color map like Matlab's "jet" using RGB values with a single parameter

Tags: rgb, colormap

Using just RGB values and a single parameter/variable I'd like to generate a multi hue color map that looks like "Jet".

It's clear for me how to do this with a single hue (blue) and a variable X like (with 0-1 RGB values):

```
color_scale = 255.0 / max(X)
x_scale = X * color_scale
color = Color(red: 0, green: x_scale/255, blue: 1, alpha: 1.0) )
```

[image: Matlab's Jet colormap]

Answer (score 0):

EDIT (solution):

Using linear combinations of RGB values doesn't create uniform brightness, using hue, solves this issue:

```
UIColor(hue: inv_scaled/359, saturation: 1, brightness: 1, alpha: 1) )
```

EDIT (incorrect):
This doesn't quite get the same hue, I'll see if I can find a better map if no one posts

```
            var blue = 0.0
            var green = 0.0
            var red = 0.0
            if scaled <= 63.75 {
                blue = 255.0
                green = scaled * 4
            } else if scaled <= 127.5 {
                blue = (127.5 - scaled) * 4
                green = scaled * 2
            } else if scaled <= 191.25 {
                green = 255.0
                red = (scaled-127.5) * 4
            } else {
                green = (191.25 - scaled) * 4
                red = scaled
            }
```